# Calling parent component method from child component written in Jsx Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I didn't expect it be tough.

I've a child component written like

**InputWrapper.vue**

```
<script>
import StyledInput from "./input";

export default {
  name: "MyInput",
  props: {
    multiline: Boolean,
    onChange: Function
  },
  render(h) {
    const { multiline, onChange } = this;
    console.log(onChange);
    return (
      <div>
        <StyledInput multiline={multiline} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
</script>
```

Then I have actual input as vue-styled-components as **Input.js**. For those familiar with styled components need not explain that code.

Then I consume this InputWrapper component in my parent component Home.vue

```
<template>


<div class="pLR15 home">
      <Row>
          <MyInput :multiline="true" placeholder="Sample Input" type="text" :onChange="handleChange"></MyInput> 
      </Row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Row from "@/ui_components/row";
import MyInput from "@/ui_components/form/input/index.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Row,
    MyInput
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange: function(e) {
      console.log("Hey you are changing my value to", e.target.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Problem** - onChange on parent is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@change.native="handleChange"` did the trick for me. Also I cleaned up all the event handlers listening on child. Since my `type` and `placeholder` properties were passing down as such, so should be the event listeners. With that thought the **.native** modifier works best for now. Although things could have been uniform by just @change="handleChange" which I was trying earlier and lead to trying out passing function as props to child.

IMP NOTE - Vuejs doesn't treats @change as normal onChange. **@input** is preferred if the idea is to capture every keystroke. Here comes the opinions! :)